# Create breadcrumb when I have a self ForeignKey table connected to M2M table

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

The problem I want to solve is in Django, but is is strongly related to how I query in the database.

I have a model/table Category that has a ForeignKey to itself:

```
|      id     |     name    |  parent_id
|       1     |     name1   |    Null
|       2     |     name2   |    Null
|       3     |     name3   |    1
|       4     |     name4   |    1
|       5     |     name5   |    3
|       6     |     name6   |    3
|       7     |     name7   |    5
```

A Parent Category can have multiple Subcategories and there is no depth limit;

Also I have a model/table Product that has a ManytoMany Relation with Category.
A Product can be in multiple Categories and a Category can have multiple Products

Intermediary Table

```
|      id     |     product_id    |  category_id  
|       1     |       1           |    1     
|       2     |       1           |    2     
|       3     |       2           |    1        
|       4     |       2           |    3    
|       5     |       3           |    5     
|       6     |       3           |    4    
|       7     |       3           |    7
```

Product Table

```
|      id     |     name    
|       1     |     name1   
|       2     |     name2   
|       3     |     name3
```

What I need:

1) for a breadcrumb to get the first set of Categories corresponding to a Product

Product Name 3: Category Id 1 -> Cat id 3 -> Cat id 7

2) Starting from a Category get all the Products in that category and its subcategories

I want to get them in few queries,  avoiding to call the database recursive from child to parent category

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use nested sets (AKA mptt) or a closure table instead. You can read this https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data for more on the various ways to model a hierarchical data structure in SQL.

Nested sets (mptt) is possibly the most involved pattern but there's a 3rd part django app which implements it: https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt.